# .py not reading from the content folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

```
|-content 
  |-utils
    |- parse_config.py
  |-models.py
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTzpA.png)
This is my folder structure in google colab.

I have already installed Pytorch and all other requirments for the project.
Here `models.py` file is not able to access the files in `utils` folder.

In my `models.py` I'm importing `utils.parse_config` which is inside the utils folder but it shows the following error.

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-6-77f4a3369184> in <module>()
----> 1 from models import *
      2 from utils import *
      3 
      4 import os, sys, time, datetime, random
      5 import torch

/content/models.py in <module>()
      9 from PIL import Image
     10 
---> 11 from utils.parse_config import *
     12 from utils.utils import build_targets
     13 from collections import defaultdict

ImportError: No module named utils.parse_config

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the "Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzvdV.png)

How do I make models.py get access to files in utils folder?

Comment: If you want to get good responses or any at all, you have to include all relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Models.py seem not in utils folder. Please recheck

Comment: I know that  models.py is not in the utils folder but I need to access the files inside the utils folder pls see the error

Answer (score 0):

what i see is that you're trying to import all from  utils.parse_config and utils scripts. 
From utils.parse_config, do

```
import *
```

since it is not in the same folder as For models.py, do

```
from ..utils.parse_config import *
```

You can try messing with your path of python, which is a easier way:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("enter the path")
from utils.parse_config import *
```

though this is generally not recommended.